# i used some youtbe video through iframe tag but problem is when mouse cursor is on iframe page its not scrolling up side and down side

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

here is my html code, what i want do when cursor on iframe when i click it plays video and when i scroll parent page scroll

```
<section class="section section-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="section-title text-center">
                    <h2>How We Work</h2>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="">
                    <iframe width=560 height=315 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wYHA_qStcqE?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder=0  allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="content">
                   <iframe width=560 height=315 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sy41imOrHbg?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add this attribute "scrolling".

```html
<section class="section section-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="section-title text-center">
                    <h2>How We Work</h2>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="">
                    <iframe scrolling="yes" width=560 height=315 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wYHA_qStcqE?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder=0  allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="content">
                   <iframe scrolling="yes" width=560 height=315 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sy41imOrHbg?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: nup i already put scrolling attribute but isn't working .. mybe scrolling attribute doesn't support in html5

Comment: Not,but I see the pages where your videos are, they only contain a single video.There are no other elements here. So you can't scoll.